# How to responsively indent an element

Tags: html, css

I have some text I want to indent by a certain amount, let's say 20px.
However, the length of the text is dynamic. If the width of the text is less than the screen width, but the text + 20px is greater than the screen width, I do not want the text to go to the next line. Rather I would like to reduce the indentation.

These are the cases I would like to accommodate:

Short text:

> |      Lorem
>   ipsum                 |

Text < screen-width, but text+20px > screen-width:

> |   Lorem ipsum dolors
>   amet|

Text = screen-width:

> |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet|

Text > screen-width:

> |Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet|
>   |consectetuer adipiscing.    |

I know this is a bit silly and it really isn't that important. But it was frustrating me that I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution... works for browsers that support `calc`.

```
<div class="indent">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing.</span>
</div>
.indent {background:pink;}
.indent span {float:right; min-width:calc(100% - 20px);}
.indent:after {content:""; display:table; clear:both;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anwPa/

Comment: This is perfect!  
Can you explain why you included the css for .indent:after? I am not sure what that line is doing and why it is needed.

Comment: since the span inside is floated, the :after serves as a clearfix to make the background color fill the div.  Otherwise, the div would not expand to contain the floated span.  Remove it in the fiddle, and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/qm92C/1/

In this example I used a little jQuery to test each paragraph element against the width of the screen - 20px. If that condition is met, the text-indent is removed. Otherwise, it's left the same.

```
$(function(){
    $("p").each(function(){
        if ($(this).width() > ($(window).width() - 20)){
            $(this).css("text-indent",0);
        };
    });
});
```

The only downside is that in order to test the width of the paragraphs, I had to change them to inline-block level elements as opposed to block level elements.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. But here's the catch. I would like it to be able to adjust on screen resize.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries to set specific CSS rules based on the width of the user device.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/